# Телеграм-бот путается когда ему пишут несколько людей

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, asyncio

Писал телеграм-бота для парсинга курса с сайта myfin. Писал сначала на telebot и всё было хорошо до момента как я решил проверить его через несколько пользователей. И получается такая система: допустим пользователь1 один отправляет ссылку на биткоин, а пользователь2 на ефир, им предлагают получить подробную информацию, и если кто-то из них нажмёт на секунду позже (допустим п2), то п1 прийдёт подробная информация по эфиру. Я уже пробовал переписать на AsyncTeleBot, не помогло. Увидел похожий вопрос, там советовали переписать на aiogram - переписал, но всё-равно не помогло, так мало-того выходит ошибка

```
ERROR:asyncio:Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x0000025537E0F670>
ERROR:asyncio:Unclosed connector
connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x0000025537AE2CA0>, 1308.062)]']
connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x0000025537E0F3A0>
```

Но она не на что не влияет вроде, то я её не трогал. Ну и поэтому я здесь. Код залил на пастбин так как большой. Извиняюсь если много лишнего текста, хотел расписать всё как можно подробней.

main.py - https://pastebin.com/raw/heTaL8gV

opengraph - https://pastebin.com/raw/UXtzdMuc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно сохранять все в базу, у какого пользователя нужна информация по Bitcoin, а у какого по Etherium.